# How can I pass a value my event.event_id from the eventlist page to everyscreen on the top.navigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, parameter-passing, react-props

How can I pass a value my event.event_id from the eventlist page to everyscreen on the top.navigator?
I don't know what to do since theya re on differe

Here is part of my routes page:

```
const Top = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

function Event () {


    return (

        <Top.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                tabBarLabelStyle: {
                    color: "#2F2E5F",
                    fontSize: 14,
                    textTransform: 'capitalize',
                    fontWeight: 700,
                },
                activeLabelStyle:{
                    fontWeight: 800,
                },
                tabBarPressColor: "transparent",
                tabBarStyle:{
                    height: 50,
                },
                tabBarContentContainerStyle: {
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                },
                tabBarIndicatorStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: "#2F2E5F",
                    height: 5,
                },

            }}
        >
            <Top.Screen name="About" component={Eventinfo} />
            <Top.Screen name="Voting" component={Eventvoting} />
            <Top.Screen name="Live Ranking" component={Eventliveranking} />
            <Top.Screen name="Schedule" component={Eventschedule} />
        </Top.Navigator>
    );
}

const EventListStack = createStackNavigator();

function EventListStackScreen() {
    return (
        <EventListStack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerLeft: null,
                headerStyle:{
                    backgroundColor: "#2F2E5F",
                },
                headerTintColor: 'white',
            }}
        >
            <EventListStack.Screen name="My Event List" component={Eventlist} />
            <EventListStack.Screen name="Event" component={Event} />
        </EventListStack.Navigator>
    );
}
```

Im having a hard time passing it and ive been getting error when trying through route